# Can't seem to SSH into AWS EC2 instance, ssh permission denied error

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I've launched a new EC2 instance with AWS using Amazon 64 bit linux (amzn-ami-2011.09.1.x86_64-ebs (ami-20506254)) and I'm having trouble ssh-ing into it. I've generated a public/private ssh keypair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and added the .pub (public) key to my key-pairs in the EC2 management console.

When I attempt to run:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws_ec2 -v ec2-46-137-17-221.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I get the following output:

```
    OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/casey/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-79-125-85-42.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [79.125.85.42] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/casey/.ssh/aws_ec2 type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/casey/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-79-125-85-42.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/casey/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/casey/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/casey/.ssh/aws_ec2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Not sure what's going on since it does offer my ssh private key but appears to just get denied. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws_ec2 -v ec2-user@ec2-79-125-85-42.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

You need to use `ec2-user` as the username.

Comment: Since the title does not specify Unix flavor, I'll let the people who come here with an UBUNTU AMI need to use: "ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws_ec2 -v ubuntu@your-instance-ip"

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 700 /Users/casey/.ssh
chmod 600 /Users/casey/.ssh/*
```

Make sure you are logging in with correct username. Default ssh users provided by aws are

```
ec2-user : RHEL/centos, etc..
ubuntu: Ubuntu
```

Also, try specifying particular key file like below.

```
ssh -i /Users/casey/.ssh/privatekey ec2-user@host.example.com
```